# MYSQL disable SELECT BENCHMARK

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-injection, benchmarking

how would I disable the mysql benchmark function, thus not being subject to blind sql injection attacks such as "select if( user() like 'root@%', benchmark(100000,sha1('test')), 'false' );"

select * from func does not show up a function benchmark.

Kind Regards
Charles

Comment: I would rather not allow people to execute any SQL on my server than disable some bits hoping people don't find ways around them. Ever heard of parametrized queries?

Comment: If your application is properly escaping data, you have not to worry about this. If you find a way to disable `benchmark`, there will be enough other ways to find out whether a query succeeds or fails.

Comment: While others have deemed your question irrelevant or useless, I do find it valuable. It seems benchmark can be used to gather information about the server, that would help an attacker to take it down (http://pastebin.com/88Lzs1XR)

Answer (score 1):

The best practice advise is to [escape data before passing to the query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Preventing_SQL_injection) or create prepared statements. Unfortunately not only benchmark function is that dangerous, so you would need to disable others ...

Comment: Hi folks, I know there may be other ways, but I explicitly want to know how to disable benchmark. Thanks, Charles

Comment: @Charles: But why? If you're using parametrized queries properly, adding this extra protection is like putting a picket fence around your concrete bunker (just in case there's people who have no problem doing through a concrete bunker but who are morbidly afraid of picket fences)

Comment: @Matti because I need to make a workshop where parametrized queries might be the answer :) And also I care for this. Of course backup option is alway to look at the source, but I hoped for some simple DISABLE BENCHMARK option.

Comment: @Matti a workshop of security basics. (Input Filter, Output Sanitizing, and some Aha Examples for the practical guys, including some countermeasures)

Answer (score 1):

I have found this answer !

```
....
echo preg_match("/^([\'\)\"a-zA-Z0-9])+([0-255[:ascii:]])+select+([0-255[:ascii:]])+([\-])+([0-255[:ascii:]])+$/","8' union select 1 from --");
echo preg_match("/^([\'\)\"\(a-zA-Z0-9])+([0-255[:ascii:]])+benchmark+([0-255[:ascii:]])+([\-])+([0-255[:ascii:]])+$/","select if( user() like 'root@%', benchmark(100000,sha1('test')), 'false' )--");
....
```

Answer (score 0):

@Charles I agree that eliminating the BENCHMARK function without first addressing root causes (input validation, etc.) is putting the horse before the cart. But I disagree that it's a picket fence or useless entirely.

Assuming that (a) it's relatively easy to disable, and (b) disabling it doesn't create new vulnerabilities, why not do it? To me it's not a second measure of defense but a first step in securing the system: disabling any and all services & functions not being used. Otherwise you're just arming an attacker's toolbox with one more potential tool - let alone a tool that's well-documented and built into every push-button BlackBox out there!

I think the biggest problem I have with your argument stems not from the debate about whether to enable or disable BENCHMARK, but your assumption that parametric queries are infallible. Putting too much faith into one system and having a false sense of security is much more dangerous than not disabling a feature like BENCHMARK. Who's to say that Oracle/Microsoft/etc. don't introduce a bug in future releases? Who's to say there isn't a bug in it right now just waiting to be discovered? And who's to say you can trust every person working on the code?